# Run a method before any component load Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I need to run a method before a component load in vuejs, It shoud trigger before showing any html in the browser.

Comment: [Vue lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks)?

Comment: try either the `created` or `mounted` hooks should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at the [beforeCreate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#beforeCreate) method.

It allows you to do stuff before data observation and event/watcher setup.